# Why doesn't INotify work with `/etc/mtab` or `/proc/mounts`?

Tags: mount, proc, inotify

When I used INotify with `/etc/mtab` or `/proc/mounts`, it doesn't detect changes when things mount or unmount, even though `/etc/mtab` and `/proc/mounts` both have changed when I check manually. Why is this, and how can I track mounting and unmounting things?

Comment: The duplicate is alsa-themed so not an exact match, but it does answer the question of why `inotify` doesn't work under `/proc`. As supplementary information, there is no alternate interface that I know of that will fire events that you can subscribe to when filesystems are mounted and unmounted. I've searched for it before.

Comment: ```stat /etc/mtab``` will tell you why the other answer is completely relevant

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the inotify man page:

> various pseudo-filesystems such as /proc, /sys, and /dev/pts are not monitorable  with
>          inotify.

and `/etc/mtab` is often just a link to /proc/mounts these days.
You can use `udisksctl monitor` to see mounts happen, or set your own `/etc/udev/rules.d/` rule file to run a program when a new device is added (before any mount), or run `dbus-monitor` to see mount events pass on that bus.  All a bit complicated.